# Formatting in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

im fairly new to latex and i have the following problem: Something is off with the formatting when i use a longer expression for the items in the enumerate enviroment:

[image]

and the output is:

[image]

This seems like a common thing but i could not find anything about it. Somehow it needs to be bounded to a line to the left and not to the right. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please privide copy of code from your editor, which we can compile. Also extend it to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try the `description` environment instead of `enumerate`.

Comment: @zarko I will do that next time i post something here, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @hair-splitter That is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.